# Value in tag html. is it possible get it?

Tags: javascript, html

**I have been helping my buddy HTML , when I realized that strange thing we did:**

```
<html>
<body>
<input name="test" value="100">  
</body>

</html>
```

*how do I retrive that value in JS.
I've tried it;*

```
var n = document.getElementById("test");
alert(n);
```

*why it show "null" ?`enter code here*

Comment: `name` and `id` are not the same.

Comment: try `document.getElementsByName("test").value`

Comment: I've forgotten my id ="test"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` attribute:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="test" name="test" value="100">  
    </body>
</html>
```

And read value:

```
var n = document.getElementById("test").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n = document.getElementById("test").value;
alert(n);
```

```html
<input id="test" value="100">
```

Use `id` attribute and `.value` to fetch its value.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `name` instead `id`:

```js
var n = document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value;
alert(n);
```

```html
<input name="test" value="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n = document.getElementById("test");
alert(n.value);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" value="1000" />
```